# How To swap arrraylist element without using any inbuilt function?

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors, swap

Could someone assist me in solving this problem? I want to swap two elements of my `ArrayList`, and I don’t want a function from the library to do it for me.

```
ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<>();
al.add(45);
al.add(54);
al.add(67);
al.add(90);
//on swapping first and second index element
int temp=al.get(1);
al.get(1)=al.get(2);
al.get(2)=temp;
```

I am unable to perform swapping. The code above cannot be compiled.

Comment: Does [`ArrayList.set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,E)) count as an "inbuilt function"?

Comment: @Sweeper You made me laugh, thanks. It’s a paradox, really, because `ArrayList.set()` is obviously an inbuilt function (and `get()` too), but I am cnovinced that Aditya Dixit meant without using [`Collections.swap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#swap(java.util.List,int,int)) and similar.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `al.set(n, newValue)` to set `newValue` to ArrayList with index `n`. Please note the first index is marked as `0` and the second index as `1`.

```java
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
al.add(45);
al.add(54);
al.add(67);
al.add(90);
System.out.println(al);
//on swapping first and second index element
int temp = al.get(0);
al.set(0, al.get(1));
al.set(1, temp);
System.out.println(al);
```

The output:

```
[45, 54, 67, 90]
[54, 45, 67, 90]
```